# Cannot obtain jwks from url http://localhost:8080/.well-known/jwks.json when using RSA

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have set up my ktor backend to support RSA verification for JWT keys. While everything was working fine earlier, suddenly I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.auth0.jwk.NetworkException: Cannot
> obtain jwks from url http://localhost:8080/.well-known/jwks.json  at
> com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getJwks(UrlJwkProvider.java:139)     at
> com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getAll(UrlJwkProvider.java:145)  at
> com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.get(UrlJwkProvider.java:163)     at
> com.auth0.jwk.RateLimitedJwkProvider.get(RateLimitedJwkProvider.java:28)
> at
> com.auth0.jwk.GuavaCachedJwkProvider.lambda$get$0(GuavaCachedJwkProvider.java:62)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4925)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3571)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2313)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2190)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2080)
> at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4012)     at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4920)
> at
> com.auth0.jwk.GuavaCachedJwkProvider.get(GuavaCachedJwkProvider.java:62)
> at app.joblink.services.JwtService.getRSAPublicKey(JwtService.kt:41)
> at
> app.joblink.services.JwtService.access$getRSAPublicKey(JwtService.kt:19)
> at
> app.joblink.services.JwtService$jwtVerifier$2.invoke(JwtService.kt:28)
> at
> app.joblink.services.JwtService$jwtVerifier$2.invoke(JwtService.kt:26)
> at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)  at
> app.joblink.services.JwtService.getJwtVerifier(JwtService.kt:26)  at
> app.joblink.plugins.SecurityKt$configureSecurity$1$1.invoke(Security.kt:15)
> at
> app.joblink.plugins.SecurityKt$configureSecurity$1$1.invoke(Security.kt:13)
> at io.ktor.server.auth.jwt.JWTAuthKt.jwt(JWTAuth.kt:324)    at
> app.joblink.plugins.SecurityKt$configureSecurity$1.invoke(Security.kt:13)
> at
> app.joblink.plugins.SecurityKt$configureSecurity$1.invoke(Security.kt:12)
> at
> io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication$Companion.install(Authentication.kt:98)
> at
> io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication$Companion.install(Authentication.kt:94)
> at
> io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationPluginKt.install(ApplicationPlugin.kt:100)
> at app.joblink.plugins.SecurityKt.configureSecurity(Security.kt:12)
> at app.joblink.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:14)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)   at
> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
> at
> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
> at
> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:188)
> at
> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:111)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:332)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:356)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:312)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
> at
> io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
> at
> io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:216)
> at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:23)   at
> app.joblink.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:34)     at
> app.joblink.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt) Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:580)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:569)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:581)    at
> java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)    at
> java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:600)    at
> java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)     at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:532)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:637)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:280)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:385)   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:407)    at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1308)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1127)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1657)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
> at com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getJwks(UrlJwkProvider.java:135)    ...
> 51 more

The trace points to my `JwtService` class, but I don't understand why. My `.well-known/jwks.json` path is set up in my Routing plugin and used to be accessible just fine.

Could this be an issue with D.I. and the order that everything is processed? Here is the service class:

```
class JwtService(
    private val jwtAudience: String,
    private val jwtIssuer: String,
    private val jwtRealm: String,
    private val jwtPK: String,
    private val userDao: UserDao
) {
    val jwtVerifier: JWTVerifier by lazy {
        JWT
            .require(Algorithm.RSA256(getRSAPublicKey(), getRSAPrivateKey()))
            .withAudience(jwtAudience)
            .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
            .build()
    }

    private val jwkProvider by lazy {
        JwkProviderBuilder(jwtIssuer)
            .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
    }

    private fun getRSAPublicKey() = jwkProvider["some-key"].publicKey as RSAPublicKey

    private fun getRSAPrivateKey(): RSAPrivateKey {
        val keySpecPKCS8 = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtPK))
        return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8) as RSAPrivateKey
    }

    fun createAccessToken(email: String): String = createJwtToken(email, AUTH_CONSTS.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN)

    fun createRefreshToken(email: String): String = createJwtToken(email, AUTH_CONSTS.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN)

    private fun createJwtToken(email: String, expireIn: Int): String =
        JWT.create()
            .withAudience(jwtAudience)
            .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
            .withClaim("email", email)
            .withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expireIn))
            .sign(Algorithm.RSA256(getRSAPublicKey(), getRSAPrivateKey()))


    suspend fun customValidator(
        credential: JWTCredential
    ): JWTPrincipal? {
        val email: String? = extractEmail(credential)
        val userFoundWithEmail: Boolean = email?.let { userDao.userExistsWithEmail(it) } ?: false

        return if (userFoundWithEmail && audienceMatches(credential)) {
            JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
        } else null
    }

    private fun audienceMatches(
        credential: JWTCredential
    ): Boolean = credential.payload.audience.contains(jwtAudience)

    fun audienceMatches(audience: String): Boolean = jwtAudience == audience

    private fun extractEmail(credential: JWTCredential): String? = credential.payload.getClaim("email").asString()
    fun getRealm(): String = jwtRealm
}
```

My Application:

```
fun Application.module() {
    configureHTTP()
    configureDependencyInjection()
    configureSerialization()
    configureSecurity()
    configureRouting()
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(Compression) {
        gzip() {
            priority = 0.9
            minimumSize(1024)
        }
        deflate() {
            priority = 1.0
            matchContentType(
                ContentType.Text.Any,
                ContentType.Application.Json
            )
            minimumSize(1024)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    EngineMain.main(emptyArray())
}
```

The Routing module contains:

`staticFiles("/.well-known/jwks.json", File("certs"), index = "jwks.json")`.

and for the koin `appModule`, the definition is:

```
val appModule = module {
    // services
    single {
        val applicationConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
        JwtService(
            applicationConfig.getString("jwt.audience"),
            applicationConfig.getString("jwt.issuer"),
            applicationConfig.getString("jwt.realm"),
            applicationConfig.getString("jwt.privateKey"),
            get()
        )
    }
    single { UserService(get(), get(), get(), get(), get()) }
}
```

The offending line seems to be the commented-out one that you can see below in my configureSecurity function:

```
fun Application.configureSecurity() {
    val jwtService: JwtService by inject()

    install(Authentication) {
        jwt("auth-jwt") {
            realm = jwtService.getRealm()
//            verifier(jwtService.jwtVerifier)

            validate { credential ->
                jwtService.customValidator(credential)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check that the JWKS endpoint is accessible from within the server? You can make a simple GET request to check that.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I'm not sure if that is possible since the crash occurs at startup, so the server does not even start as of right now

Comment: Then you can remove the code that causes the crash.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman the url is accessible and does indeed return the data

Comment: I have added the potential source of the issue. It seems to be the jwt verifier function call in my configureSecutity module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am still unsure, as to what the actual is may be, I have managed to find a fix.

Instead of relying on the `JwtService` to provide the verifier instance, I went with the approach of defining it within the module, as seen [in the ktor docs](https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html#validate-payload). Now, my `configureSecurity()` looks like this:

```
fun Application.configureSecurity() {
    val jwtService: JwtService by inject()

    val issuer = environment.config.property("jwt.issuer").getString()
    val audience = environment.config.property("jwt.audience").getString()
    val myRealm = environment.config.property("jwt.realm").getString()
    val jwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder(issuer)
        .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()

    install(Authentication) {
        jwt("auth-jwt") {
            realm = myRealm
            verifier(jwkProvider, issuer) {
                withAudience(audience)
                withIssuer(issuer)
                acceptLeeway(3)
            }

            validate { credential ->
                jwtService.customValidator(credential)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to fix the crash and everything works just fine. As to the root cause of the original issue, I have only managed to pinpoint that it was being caused by the `jwtService.jwtVerifier` instance being used. That seemed to be calling the `getRSAPublicKey()` which would then attempt to create the `jwkProvider` lazily, and then crash.

```
private val jwkProvider by lazy {
    JwkProviderBuilder(jwtIssuer)
        .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
}

 private fun getRSAPublicKey() = jwkProvider["3nGxSDQMSbeyMhuFT79exJ2hfnP8am"].publicKey as RSAPublicKey
```

If someone figures out a fix for the issue while still using the `JwtService` class, I will accept that answer.